# How do I select an available room from the Booking table with specific 'RoomType' ? In c# code behind using the SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

This is my `Booking` table:

[image]

The `roomNo` here is a foreign key referencing `Room` table.

And this is my `Room` table:

[image]

Is there any method to get the list of available `roomNo` where `Date1 != checkinDate` and `Date2 != checkoutDate`?

C# project using SQL server.

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do a `JOIN` between the tables on `roomno` column saying `on booking.roomno = room.roomno` along with a `WHERE` condition like `where Date1 != checkinDate and Date2 != checkoutDate.`